# Doubt in Lee Smooth Manifolds Proposition 6.5

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, differential-topology

Proposition 6.5 from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds is the proposition that if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero and $F : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth function, then $F(A)$ also has measure zero.

In the proof, we use the following: "Since $\overline{U}$ is compact $C$ such that $|DF(x)| \leq C$ for all $ x\in \overline{U}$". Initially my intuition for this statement was that F is bounded on a compact set, so its partial derivatives are bounded, so the determinant of the jacobian |DF(a)| is bounded, but I'm not sure if that makes much sense.

I'd appreciate any hints on how I can get started proving that the determinant of the jacobian is bounded on a compact set.

Comment: The important bit is not that the partial derivatives are bounded, but that they are continuous. That makes the Jacobian continuous as well, and with it its determinant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the expression $|DF(x)|$ denotes the Frobenius norm, not the determinant. See Example B.47 in my smooth manifolds book.

It certainly does not follow from the fact that $F$ is bounded that its partial derivatives are also bounded. But because $F$ is smooth, the matrix entries of $DF(x)$ (which are just the partial derivatives of the component functions of $F$) are continuous functions of $x$. Thus $|DF(x)|$ is a continuous real-valued function of $x$, so it achieves a maximum value on the compact set $\overline U$.